# I did injured from the accident

Tags: accent, word-stress

Consider this sentence: I injured from the accident.

For emphasizing that I really injured from the accident, which sentence should I use?

1- I did injure from the accident.

2- I did injured from the accident.

Comment: Do you mean that an accident happened, that you have described the accident in a previous sentence, and that you suffered an injury as a result of that accident?

Comment: @BoldBen  yes, exactly

Comment: In that case the correct form is "I _was injured in_ the accident". In this case the passive voice is the only appropriate one since the victim, usually, has not caused his or her own injury. When the victim has had agency, whether by carelessness or deliberate self harm, the correct for is _reflexive_. That is, for example, "I _injured myself_ when I fell off my bike". Neither of the sentences you give is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb *injure* needs an object. Who or what was injured? If you injured *yourself*, tell us: "I injured myself" or "I was injured."

We only say "I **did** injure myself!" to add emphasis; for example, if no-one believes us. There are examples of this use of the verb *do* [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/do) (definition 3 under "Auxiliary verb".)

We injure ourselves (or get injured) **in** an accident, not *from* one. So you might say, "I was injured in the accident."

Finally, if you want to say you were **badly** hurt, you can say,"I was (really/terribly/extremely) badly injured in the accident."

Comment: `I did injure from the accident` is not grammatically correct.  But does it at least convey the message I described to convey?

Comment: @Admia: Maybe. I might **guess** what you mean. If you have wounds I _will_ guess what you mean.  If you seem OK I may ask _who_ was injured. Or I might ask, "Have you injured someone?" If you say " _the_ accident" I will ask "_what_ accident?" Why are you asking this?

Comment: Just wanted to know if at least the message can be conveyed regardless of grammar correctness.

Comment: How about this?  `I did incur injury from the accident`.

Comment: @Admia Yes. That kind of structure is common among people whose first language is not English. Bear in mind the 2nd paragraph of my answer (about emphasis). It should be "I incurred an injury in the accident." It's probably outside the remit of this group to teach bad English :-) but your sentence would be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your suggestions is grammatical. You could say it this way:

> I **did** get injured in the accident.

The word "did" should be emphasized in speech.

Comment: I'm not sure this clears up how to express their meaning.

Comment: In formal written, using the verb `get` may not be standard. So although the expression `did get injured` seems to convey the message, the expression is not preferable.